# regex for phone number validation?

Tags: regex, validation, phone-number

i want to validate my phone number with the regex for following formats.i have googled the things but i could not find the regex for following formats...

```
    079-26408300 / 8200
    (079) 26408300
    079 264 083 00 
    9429527462
```

can anyone please guide me how can i do validate the phone number field for above formats?
I want to validate the phone number for only above formats as right now am using only following regex `var phone_pattern = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;`

@Ali Shah Ahmed

```
var phone_pattern = "(\d{10})|(\d{3}-\d{8}\s/\s\d{4})|((\d{3}\s){3}\d{2})|((\d{3})\s\d{8})";
```

here is the way am checking if its valid

```
if (!phone_pattern.test(personal_phone))
        {
            $("#restErrorpersonalphone").html('Please enter valid phone number');
            $("#personal_phone").addClass('borderColor');
            flag = false;
        } else {
            $("#restErrorpersonalphone").html('');
            $("#personal_phone").removeClass('borderColor');
        }
```

its not working. Am I implementing in wrong way?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just strip away everything but numbers and deal with the raw numbers, no spaces, parentheses, pluses, etc?

Comment: ok..let say i dont want parenthesis +.but its required to use - ..please see my updated question

Comment: Have you search SO for this before posting? There are many post about validating a phone number.

Comment: Yes I searched but couldnt find the way i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets start with the simplest phone number `9429527462`

As this has 10 characters and all are numbers, regex for it could be `\d{10}`

Now the next phone number `079 264 083 00`. Regex for this pattern could be `(\d{3}\s){3}\d{2}`
First we are expecting a group of 3 digits and a space to repeat thrice `(\d{3}\s){3}`, this will cover `079 264 083` (space included in it), so left will be the last two characters which are handled using `\d{2}`

For the phone number `(079) 26408300`, `\(\d{3}\)\s\d{8}` regex could be use. The regex first looks for a opening bracket, then three digits inside it, and then the closing bracket. It then looks for a space, and then for 8 digits.

The phone number `079-26408300 / 8200` could be validated using regex `\d{3}-\d{8}\s/\s\d{4}`. It first looks for 3 digits then a -, then 8 digits followed by a space. Then looks for a / and then a space and then 4 digits.

If you wish to know a single regex for validating all the above patterns, do let me know.

Final combined regex would be:

```
/(\d{10})|(\d{3}-\d{8}\s\/\s\d{4})|((\d{3}\s){3}\d{2})|(\(\d{3}\)\s\d{8})/
```

Comment: yes ..if u can provide me single regex then it will be useful..thanks for this wonderful answer with details

Comment: well i would keep it as simple as possible.
"(\d{10})|(\d{3}-\d{8}\s/\s\d{4})|((\d{3}\s){3}\d{2})|(\(\d{3}\)\s\d{8})"
(Please note there is no need of quotation marks, i put these just to seperate the regex from rest of the comment)
I believe this regex would do the work.
What i did is just combined all the mentioned regex with OR statements. So it would match all the mentioned patterns.

Comment: can u please see my updated question am quite new in this regex so..please help me as i dont know how i put this in my javascript

Comment: there are some small mistakes. Firstly do not put your regex in inverted commas.
var phone_pattern = /(\d{10})|(\d{3}-\d{8}\s/\s\d{4})|((\d{3}\s){3}\d{2})|((\d{3})\s\d{8})/
start and end your regex with a forward slash.
Secondly, the regex contains a forward slash in itself, try replacing that forward slash with a backslash and a forward slash, "\/"
So finally the code will look like:
var phone_pattern = /(\d{10})|(\d{3}-\d{8}\s\/\s\d{4})|((\d{3}\s){3}\d{2})|((\d{3})\s\d{8})/

Comment: hey i just noticed that two of the backslashes are removed in the comment, so i updated my answer with the final regex. Try following the steps mentioned in my previous comment, and replace the final regex with the one mentioned in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23613/discussion-between-bhavik-kama-and-ali-shah-ahmed)

Comment: can u pelase come to chatroom..there some issues want to discuss

Comment: This is the correct methodology, but I have not seen anyone correct the mistake with the parenthesis version being applied to the rest.  It has to be made optional. You do this with `?` after it.  And why escape the parenthesis when it can be written `[(]?` and `[)]?`.  Looks way better, to me.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward solution is simple, use |

```
String ex = "\\d{3}-\\d{8} / \\d{4}|\\(\\d{3}\\) \\d{8}|...
```